# Validating HTML5 DOCTYPE. Validating source on Localhost

Tags: html, doctype, validation

I have been contemplating if I should go all out on HTML5 and CSS3 and the hell with supporting all browsers. That said....

What is the best way to validate HTML5 in my development Env. (localhost on my computer at home WindowsXP)

I use Firefox mostly for dev, now and then I pop into google chrome... I do not use or care to use IE8

I used to like the Firefox Add-on "HTML Validator version 0.9.5.2". Was great to validate DOCTYPES before HTML5. but those days are over :(

So. what are people using to validate HTML5? Specially localhost

Comment: IMO you're asking a "shopping list question", which is [considered not to be a good fit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/162730) on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Web Developer Extension for Google Chrome and Firefox](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) supports local HTML5 validation, it's always worked great for me.

Comment: Man you made my day! Thank you. What's more awesome is that, under Windows, you can use `Alt+Shift+L` to invoke the local validation function. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

The official W3C HTML validator: http://validator.w3.org/

They also have a CSS validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

These can be installed locally using the Download links at the bottom of each validator, for example: http://code.w3.org/unicorn/wiki/Documentation/Install